# Error message when running a SQL maintenance plan backup

Tags: backup, maintenance

I'm receiving the following error message when my daily maintenance backup plans execute:

Error Message 1:

> [298] SQLServer Error: 407, Internal error. The string routine in file e:\sql11_main_t\sql\ntdbms\storeng\dmu\dbcc\source\dumplog.cpp, line 5473 failed with HRESULT 0x8007007a. [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnExecuteCachableOp)

Error Message 2:

> [298] SQLServer Error: 8630, Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor encountered an unexpected error during execution (HRESULT = 0x80040e19). [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnExecuteCachableOp)

What can I do to fix these errors and get my backups to run successfully again?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to fix these errors

Open support ticket

> get my backups to run successfully again

Try to run backup manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

```
BACKUP DATABASE myDatabase ...
```

If it runs, get rid of maintenance plans and replace them with Ola Hallengren Maintenance Solution https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to run the manual backup.  I did attempt it but still received the same errors.  Thank you for the input.